# CSS - 2 Column Layout

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I want to create a 2 column liquid layout with a nav bar on the left side that should have a height of 100%, a header that should have a width of 100% and a content section that should have a height and width of 100% as well, and there should be a margin on all sides of 10 or 20 pixels, and also in between the header, nav and content boxes. Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2Lnq6sd/1/

```
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Now as you can see the nav bar is not 100% in height and the content section is too wide. My final result should look like this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img921/9425/UYp8Ah.png

Tried finding help on google on this issue but I still don't get what I should use, relative or absolute positions and which to use for which attribute. any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're good to go: http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/vKxVYv?editors=1100

- nav bar **is** 100% in height
- the content section is **not** too
  wide

```css
html, body {
    height:calc(100% - 60px);
}
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

header {
  float:left;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav {
  float:left;
  margin-top:20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

section {
  float:right;
  margin-top:20px;
  height:100%;
  padding: 10px;
  width:calc(100% - 220px); 
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <header>
        This is the header
    </header>
  
    <nav>
        This is the nav
    </nav>

    <section>
        This is the main section
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, however I am mister perfect and I would want the right side of the header and content to match, check image: http://imageshack.com/a/img923/1834/jd6eip.png - Any ideas on this? Will accept this answer if we can fix this :)

Comment: @Ron, made some changes (basically added box-sizing: border-box; and fixed some values) I think now is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and see demo:

CSS:

```
body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: verdana;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% 0;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 75%;
}
```

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d2Lnq6sd/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I changed a few things:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2Lnq6sd/9/

```
body,html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 73%;
    float: left;
    height:auto;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

aside {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I have moved your navigation into an aside tag, this is just HTML 5 syntax [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp)

By using floats and keeping the positions as they were you are able to create the desired effect. To get the width to 100% I would recommend playing with the padding and margins to get it to a 20% + 80% ratio.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Do you need like this ,

Html:
<div class="container">

    <header>
        This is the header
    </header>

    <nav>
        This is the nav
    </nav>

    <section>
        This is the main section
    </section>

</div>
Css:
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  width:675px;

  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 300px;
  bottom:200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}



you can see the link:https://jsfiddle.net/d2Lnq6sd/11/
```

Answer (score -2):

You can position nav as fixed, use below to get an idea.

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 76px;
}
```